# Regex for preg_match with English and Japanese words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, cjk

I'm reading csv file with English and Japanese character included cells.
One of the cell data is like below.

```
1: Sumanaseka Sasith 2018/9/19 (水) 13:27

Human have a altruistic feeling when help another with somethings. People are forgetting that because of the selfish motives they have.

We must compress that selfishness to help some to have that altruistic feeling.
```

For above example I have created a regex below.

$x[$i] = data variable from the for loop.

```
preg_match("/(\d*\:)\s((\w*)\s(\w*))\s([12]\d{3}\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))\s\(.*\)\s([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})(.*)/s", $x[$i], $matches)
```

This is working fine. But, for below data its not working because of the Japanese characters.

```
2: 齋藤 伸久 2018/2/8 (木) 06:55


https://www.google.com

I will study with you all the way of thinking as a company.

I will study Mr inamori 74 philosophies
```

Does anyone know about capturing "2: 齋藤 伸久 2018/2/8 (木) 06:55" Japanese characters for this example.
Thank you.

Comment: *You forgot to specify the u [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).*

Comment: Also, make `0` optional in `0[1-9]|`. Add `?` after it. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZxbYPe/1).

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved the problem.